# How to save selected input from a drop-down box with checkboxes? My drop-down box is okay but the checkboxes are not working

Tags: python-3.x, string, checkbox, drop-down-menu, wxpython

> Hi, I am trying to run a GUI based on wx. I made checkboxes in a drop-down list. But the checkboxes are not working. I want the checkboxes to work and save the selected input option names somewhere. Here is the code. With these selected input option names (one or more than one) I will filter a big string later. Thank you in advance :)

```
import wx
import wx.stc
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin

class CheckListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT | 
                wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self)
        ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
        self.SetSize(-1, -1, -1, 50)

    def OnCheckItem(self, index, flag):
        item = self.GetItem(index)
        if flag:
            what = "checked"
        else:
            what = "unchecked"

        print(f'{item.GetText()} - {what}')

class ListViewComboPopup(wx.ComboPopup):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.ComboPopup.__init__(self)
        self.lc = None

    def AddItem(self, txt):
        self.lc.InsertItem(0, txt)


    def Init(self):
        self.value = -1
        self.curitem = -1

    def Create(self, parent):
        self.lc = CheckListCtrl(parent)
        self.lc.InsertColumn(0, '', width=90)
        return True

    def GetControl(self):
        return self.lc

    def OnPopup(self):
        wx.ComboPopup.OnPopup(self)

    def GetAdjustedSize(self, minWidth, prefHeight, maxHeight):
        return wx.ComboPopup.GetAdjustedSize(
            self, minWidth, 110, maxHeight)

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Popup Menu Tutorial")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        comboCtrl = wx.ComboCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Select filter")    
        popupCtrl = ListViewComboPopup()
        comboCtrl.SetPopupControl(popupCtrl)
        popupCtrl.AddItem("mango")
        popupCtrl.AddItem("cat")
        popupCtrl.AddItem("dog")
        popupCtrl.AddItem("tiger")
        popupCtrl.AddItem("three")
        popupCtrl.AddItem("hat")
        popupCtrl.AddItem("hot")
        popupCtrl.AddItem("sweden")
        popupCtrl.AddItem("kth")
```

Comment: Note: `The CheckListCtrlMixin class has been made redundant by new checkbox features in the wx.ListCtrl class. It is advised to switch your code to use that instead of this mixin.`

Answer (score 0):

You can saev them as variables in a .txt file with pickle:

```
pickle.dump(your_variable, open("path/to/your/file.txt", "wb"))
```

and to access them:

```
your_variable = pickle.load(open("path/to/your/file.txt", "rb"))
```